# Architecture for an Auction Style Site

Tags: asp.net

Where would be a good place to find information on the underlying architecture for auction style sites?  Preferably in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 4):

At least from the data architecture aspect, the [Database Answers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) web site has some database diagrams that can usually help kickstart to thinking around the domain model.  There is an auction diagram there, as well.

Comment: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/auction/index.htm